# How to Clear terminal screen c++ on mac osx using codeblocks?

Tags: c++, macos

I'm using codeblocks (c++) on a mac. I usually use system("cls") when using a windows machine. How can I use something similar on the mac? thanks.

Answer (score 5):

macOS uses `system("clear");`

though there are [better solutions](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/4z18T05o/#POSIX)